# Consumir serviço REST pelo Angular - Retornar JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Tenho a seguinte function em angular que consome um servico:

```
function GetDados($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/dados').success(function(data){
        $scope.dados = data;
    });
}
```

preciso que o $scope.dados vá para a este lugar

```
<div ng-controller="GetDados">
    <script>
        var json = $scope.dados;
```

Não funciona. Não sei se isso é permitido.

O que tenho em dados é um `json` com vários registros. O erro que me mostra é que não reconhece a variável $scope. Obrigado.

Solução!

```
function GetDados($scope, $http){
$http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/dados').
    success(function(data){
    //$scope.dados = data;

            var json = data;
```

Meu objetivo era construir um grafico utilizando o retorno do serviço. Coloquei o script do grafico no mesmo da chamada do serviço e utilizei. O ng-bind que o colega citou ajudou também.

Comment: Podes colocar o código do teu controller? Pelo menos a parte onde você registra ele

Comment: Aliais, por que você não trabalha com esse dado dentro do controller?

Comment: o meu controller é a function GetDados.. não trabalho dentro do controller pq tá separado em arquivos.. o controller tá em um arquivo separado e o retorno dele é para gerar um gráfico que coloquei no arquivo html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece por que para você passar o resultado de um controller do Angular para a view (html) você precisa fazer um `bind`. Isso é feito de 2 modos:

- `<p>{{ nomeDoScope }}</p>`
- `<p ng-bind="nomeDoScope"></p>`

Deste modo, supondo que você tenha um `$scope` assim `$scope.nomeDoScope = 'Meu teste'`, o valor que seria exibido na tela seria apenas "Meu Teste", ou seja, no seu caso seria exibido o `JSON`.

Lembrando que não precisa estar dentro de uma tag `p`, ele pode estar em qualquer elemento, desde que siga aquela padrão.

No seu exemplo seria: `{{dados}}`

**Quando usar um ou outro?**

Há controvérsias e até especulações sobre a performance de usar `{{}}` ou usar a diretiva `ngBind`. De fato há uma diferença de performance (`ngBind` é melhor), porém muito mínima, ela irá ter algum impacto somente quando usada em grande escala, e eu digo *GRANDE ESCALA MESMO*! Na maioria dos casos não influenciam.

#### ngBind

Então, considerando um cenário onde você possua muitos bindings, especialmente dentro de um texto extenso, o ideal seria usar a diretiva ngBind. Imagine que você tenha um elemento `p` que gere um texto de 2mil linhas, ao usar o método `{{}}` o escopo de análise não está definido, por isso a validação irá percorrer todo o texto até encontrar o bind e assim aplicá-lo. Já ao usar o ngBind, o escopo está definido e abrange somente o pedaço de texto que deve ser atualizado, logo a performance é melhor.

Exemplo:

```
<p>Aqui inicia nosso texto de exemplo muito...
    [..muito texto..] 
    <span ng-bind="meuEscopo"></span> e aqui continua nosso texto extenso...
    [...muito texto...]
</p>
```

#### {{ }}

É usado na maioria dos casos. Por que? Simplicidade. Imagine ter que criar um elemento `span` só para colocar um pedaço de texto? Chato né? Pois é.. Por isso na maioria dos casos o uso de `{{}}` é preferencial, e como dito acima, a diferença de performance não é tão significativa.

Se você tiver um elemento de título que será usado somente para exibir o título, não custa nada usar o `ngBind`, exemplo: `<h6 ng-bind="meuEscopo"></h6>`.

Exemplo:

```
<p>Aqui temos um exemplo curto com {{meuEscopo}} e aqui ele finaliza</p>
```

Mas não há necessidade de fazer isso só para um único elemento.

Acho que assim fica mais claro para você entender.

Comment: pelo que entendi seria assim: <div ng-bind="dados">
            <script>
                var json = {{dados}};

Comment: Esquece a parte de <script>, não precisa disso =D

Comment: sim..kkk... eu coloquei isso pq no html estou gerando um grafico usando o chart.js e a fonte de dados é um json retornado pelo serviço, consumido pelo angular

Comment: Mas não há necessidade. O angular irá se encarregar de atribuir o valor do $scope quando ele for referenciado na página. =D Obs.: Editei minha resposta para complementar a explicação.

Comment: muitissimo obrigado! aprendi mais um pouco de angular hoje!

Comment: Não comentei pra não estender muito a resposta.. Mas complementar a isso, recomendo que procure por "One-Way data binding" que seria assim: `{{::meuEscopo}}` mas pesquise antes de usar, pois ele limita o fluxo que o dado é atualizado